# Characterize $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ such that the derivative is surjective

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

**Exercise:** Characterize all the open subset $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ such that $D: \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}}(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}}(U)$, $f \mapsto f'$ is surjective. $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}}(-)$ the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$.

I guess the answer is: $U$ must be simply connected, but I am not able to prove it. If $U$ is simply connected then for each $g \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}}(U)$ a primitive is given by:
$$z \mapsto \int_{z_0}^{z} gdz$$
where $z_0$ is a given point in $U$ and we integrate on a path from $z_0$ to $z$ in $U$. Is it true that if $U$ is not simply connected then there always exists an holomorphic map on $U$ which doesn't have a primivite?
Thank you.

**EDIT:** I thought about this solution: let $\gamma$ be non trivial a path in $U$. Let us call $V$ the bounded open region whose $\gamma$ is the boundary ($V$ is unique because $\gamma$ divides $\mathbb{C}$ in two open regions and only one is bounded). Being $U$ open and $\gamma$ a path in $U$ there must be points of $U$ in $V$. Moreover being $\gamma$ non trivial there must be also points of $V$ which are not in $U$. In the end there exists a point $z_0 \notin U$ which is surrounded by a closed path in $U$ so the function $\frac{1}{z-z_0}$ is holomorphic in $U$ but it doesn't have a primitive in $U$. Is this solution correct?

Comment: As a starting point, consider the function $\frac{1}{z}$ on $\mathbb{C}-0$. It doesn't have a primitive. You can try to construct similar functions for any non simply connected $U$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $U$ is not simply connected, then there is a loop $\gamma\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow U$ such that its winding number with respect to a $p\in\mathbb{C}\setminus U$ is not $0$ (because $U$ is not simply connected if and only if its complement on the Riemann sphere is disconnected). Therefore, $\frac1{z-p}$ has no primitive in $U$, since if it had a primitive $F$, then the winding number would be$$\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac1{z-p}\,\mathrm dz=F\bigl(\gamma(1)\bigr)-F\bigl(\gamma(0)\bigr)=0.$$

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. I guess you meant that $U$ is simply connected iff its complement on the Riemann sphere is connected, do you? Could you tell me if my solution is correct before I close the question? Thank you.

Comment: Actually, what I meant to write was that $U$ is *not* simply connected if and only if its complement on the Riemann sphere is disconnected (I've edited my answer). There is a (not very serious) problem with you solution. It is not true that the image of $\gamma$ divides $\mathbb C$ in just two regions. That would be true if $\gamma$ was a simple loop, but you did not assume that. Apart from that, it seems to me that it is correct.

Comment: You're right, I guess I can correct it simply by calling $V$ the bounded region embraced by $\gamma$ and then everything is ok, is it?

Comment: @Federico Yes, I think so.